# Calling a method for multiple values in a file

Tags: java

I'm reading in this file from the command line on the program below:

```
Student1  
5
a Activities  0.05  
q Quizzes 0.10  
p Projects 0.25   
e Exams 0.30  
f Final 0.30  

**a100 a95 a100 a100 a100  
q90 q80 q100 q80 q80 r90  
p100 p95 p100 p85 p100  
e77.5 e88  
f92**
```

**GradeBookApp.java**

```
public class GradeBookApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  String fileName = "";
  String name = "";
  char[] categoryCodes = new char[5];
  String[] categories = new String[5];
  double[] categoryWeights = new double[5];
  double[][] gradeTable;


  if (args.length > 0) {

     for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Reading file \"" + args[i] + "\"." 
           + "\n\tCreating GradeBook object."
           + "\n\tAdding grades to GradeBook object."
           + "\nProcessing of file complete.");


        fileName = args[i];
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        name = scanFile.nextLine();
        int catCodes = Integer.parseInt(scanFile.nextLine());

        for (i = 0; i < catCodes; i++) {
           String[] all = scanFile.nextLine().split(" ");
           if(all.length == 3 && all[0].length() == 1 && all[2].matches("(\\d+\\.\\d+)")){
              categoryCodes[i] = all[0].charAt(0);
              categories[i] = all[1];
              categoryWeights[i] = Double.parseDouble(all[2]);
           }
        }

        GradeBook myGB = new GradeBook (name, categoryCodes, 
           categories, categoryWeights);
}
}
```

I have another class containing the method "addGrade" that takes in a parameter "newGradeIn". This parameter is the grade from the file being read in i.e. a100 or e88. For each grade being added, I'm replacing the original 2D array with one that holds one more item.

```
public boolean addGrade(String newGradeIn) {     

  char row = newGradeIn.charAt(0);
  int grade = Integer.parseInt(newGradeIn.substring(1));

  double[] oldArr = gradeTable[row];
  double[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(oldArr, oldArr.length + 1);
  newArr[newArr.length - 1] = grade;
  gradeTable[row] = newArr;
  return row != 0; 
}
```

I'm completely blanking on how to do this. I know I should probably use a for-each loop, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Where are you reading the file? what is `String newGradeIn` ? which array you should update? how do you "add" values to array which is full? copy it into a bigger array? your question lacks many details, either fix it or it'll be closed as "unclear"

Comment: `row` is of type `char` and you're using it as an index to the `gradeTable`. By doing that the `char` is converted to an `int` (so the character `'a'` would be converted to 97 for example) - but I doubt that this is what you want...

Comment: @drewmoore instead of continuing to argue, now that you can run his code - add your "fix" and see if that's related to the issue or not. If it fixes his problem I'll remove the downvote and upvote your answer.

Comment: @alfsin no that's not what I want. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @alfsin Grade Table is supposed to be a 2D array of grade categories and the grades in each category. The addGrade method is supposed to take in a grade, place it in the appropriate part of the 2D array, and make room for one more grade in the array. Is that not what the method is doing now?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use the `a` from the grade `a100` in order to store `100` as the grade for student `a` you should consider using a `Map` instead of a 2D array. For example:

```
Map<String, double[]> gradeTable = new HashMap<>();

public void addGrade(String newGradeIn) {
    String row = newGradeIn.substring(0,1); // use the 'a' as a key in the hashmap to the grades of student `a`
    int grade = Integer.parseInt(newGradeIn.substring(1));
    double[] oldArr = gradeTable.get(row);
    if (oldArr == null) { // when you start - the hash-map is empty so we need to initialize the array
        oldArr = new double[0];
    }
    double[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(oldArr, oldArr.length + 1);
    newArr[newArr.length - 1] = grade;
    gradeTable.put(row, newArr);
}
```

The usage is pretty straight forward:

```
GradeBook g = new GradeBook();
g.addGrade("a100");
g.addGrade("a95");
g.addGrade("b90");
g.addGrade("b95");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g.gradeTable.get("a"))); // [100.0, 95.0]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g.gradeTable.get("b"))); // [90.0, 95.0]
```